# Как перевести string в массив integer в с++?

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

```
#include <string>
int main()
{ 
string S="74 319 432 82 95 0 1";
int N[numb]; //numb - количество целых чисел в строке S

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Функции atoi и strchr для поиска пробела вас вполне спасут.

Comment: Можете посмотреть [тут](http://pastebin.com/6XBP0KZH) (только передавать надо.c_str() (или работайте просто с сишными строками))

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

[Решение](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bg0COjErKYeJvnKc) в духе stl (вектор вместо сырого массива):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    string s = "74 319 432 82 95 0 1"; 
    stringstream ss(s);
    vector<int> v;

    copy(istream_iterator<int>(ss), {}, back_inserter(v));
    copy(begin(v), end(v), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Плюсанул @alexolut, но решил предложить:

[Решение](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BCgjjV3w0MT4a1kP) с частичкой духа stl (вектор вместо сырого массива, но без stringstream):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    string s = "74 319 432 82 95 0 1"; 
    vector<int> v;

    auto ptr = s.c_str();
    char *endptr = nullptr;
    while (ptr != s.c_str() + s.size()) {
        auto value = strtol(ptr, &endptr, 10);
        if (ptr == endptr) {
            ptr++;
        } else {
            ptr = endptr;
            v.push_back(value);
        }
    }

    copy(begin(v), end(v), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")); 
}
```

Проверка:

```
if (ptr == endptr)
```

нужна, что бы пропустить невалидный символ и не зациклиться (попробуем следующий). При таком раскладе подобный вход:

```
string s = "f74 319 a432 82 95 0 1";
```

тоже будет обработан: всё, не числовое будет отброшено.

Стоит ещё проверять `errno` на `ERANGE`, и пытаться применять, например, `strtoll()`

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо выделить подстроки при помощи поиска разделителя (в данном случае - пробела).
Каждая подстрока преобразуется в число с помощью функций `stoi` и полученные значения заносятся в массив.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, для начинающего самое простое такое -

если знаете точно `numb`:

```
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    const int numb = 7;
    string S = "74 319 432 82 95 0 1";
    int N[numb]; //numb - количество целых чисел в строке S
    istringstream ss(S);
    for(int i = 0; i < numb; ++i)
        ss >> N[i];

    for(auto i : N)
        cout << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

если не знаете -

```
int main()
{
    string S = "74 319 432 82 95 0 1";
    vector<int> N;
    int n;
    istringstream ss(S);

    while(ss >> n) N.push_back(n);

    for(auto i : N)
        cout << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```