# Инициализировать вектор с помощью строки C++

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, vector

Необходимо инициализировать вектор с помощью пользовательского ввода.
К примеру пользователь вводит 1 2 3 5 104 1034 , в векторе должны содержаться элементы которые ввел пользователь. Можно ли как нибудь это сделать без использования регулярных выражений?

Comment: Пользователь вводит все в одну строку

Comment: Предположим у нас есть строка
string x="1 10 2 1023 500";
Необходимо из нее сделать вектор, не важно в каком формате будут храниться данные в векторе(числах или строках).
Необходимо просто распарсить эту строку и ею инициализировать массив.Так вроде проще объяснил. Но желательно, что бы сразу со ввода пользовательского инициализация шла.

Comment: Сразу парсить ввод (из `cin`) - можно брать мое решение (и тогда плевать даже, в скольки строках будет ввод), из строки `x` - через `stringstream`. Кстати, можно как у Abyx, просто используя `istream_iterator<int> first(cin)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/498094/176217

Comment: @MNikita, если вам был дан исчерпывающи ответ, то отметьте его верным (галка напротив выбранного ответа)

Answer (score 5):

Пожалуй, простейший способ - если вводятся только те же целые числа, то просто вводить их в цикле:

```
vector<int> v;
int n;
while(cin >> n) v.push_back(n);
```

Как только будет прочтено НЕ целое число, `cin` перейдет в состояние `fail` (из-за неверного формата ожидаемого числа) и ввод прекратится. Останется обработать этот нечисленный ввод. Никаких регулярных выражений.

Если это не совсем то, что надо - поясните ваш вопрос подробнее.

Answer (score 3):

Если на входе строка, то можно поступить следующим способом (код можно проверить [здесь](http://ideone.com/xRwMqd)). Преобразовывать в числа или нет - смотрите сами (в данном варианте перед выводом преобразуются).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string str= "1 2 3 5 104 1034";
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::vector <std::string> v;
    for(std::string word;ss>>word;v.push_back(word));
    for(auto&x:v)std::cout << std::stoi(x) << " ";
}
```

Comment: Код работает, спасибо. Не могли бы вы объяснить как он работает?

Comment: Пожалуйста. Но что именно в нем непонятно? Может уточните? А если в общих чертах, то мы имеем строку. Эту строку "преобразуем" в поток. Если понятнее, то в объект, аналогичный тому же cin или сout (стандартным потокам ввода или вывода). Далее создаем наш вектор вектор (пустой изначально). В цикле  считываем из потока слова. Как в стандартном потоке ввода пробел будет являться разделителем. Т.е. по сути будет происходить нечто аналогичное, как в ответе Harry, только уже постфактум. Ну и в конце в цикле выводятся значения из векторов.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать `stringstream` и например `istream_iterator`

```
std::string s = "1 20 30";
std::stringstream stream(s);
std::istream_iterator<int> first(stream), last;
std::vector<int> v(first, last);
```

Comment: Вряд ли ТС-у понятно, как это может работать (например, зачем тут `last` (это некое магическое слово в данном контексте?), каким образом этот итератор взаимодействует с `first` (который довольно очевидно (или не очень очевидно?) связан с исходной строкой)?)

Comment: Ну, хоть намекните, что `istream_iterator last` default инициалиpуется состоянием EOF (или как там у вас правильно?) и поэтому в range-конструкторе вектора задает диапазон с открытой верхней границей.

Comment: Смысл тот же, поскольку файл это тоже последовательность байтиков. А написано так: `This kind of iterator has a special state as an end-of-stream iterator, which is acquired when the end of the stream is reached` (надеюсь, теперь наш знаток питона въедет в суть крестов).